# Hey all I'm new to python and i'm having a problem here can you guys help me out! (the file exist)

Tags: python

```
f = open('buddy.txt','r')
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
```

error:

```
 File "c:\Users\97798\Desktop\python\Chapter_09\01_files.py", line 10, in <module>
    f = open('buddy.txt','r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'buddy.txt'
```

Comment: The error message pretty much says it: you can't open for reading a file that doesn't already exist. If you open a file for writing/appending, then yes, it will create the file, but it doesn't make sense to do the same for reading.

Comment: Your python code and `buddy.txt` should be in the same directory. Make sure if both files are in the same directory, if not, move one of the file to other's.

Answer (score 0):

There are various modes to open files. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/19261326) to understand them. In your case, if you want to create a file when it doesn't exist and then continue, you can use `w+`. Also, in most cases you would want to handle errors that arise out of file operations with `try` and `except` statements.

```
fName = 'buddy.txt'
try:
    with open(fName, 'w+') as f:
        # do things with the file    
except OSError:
    print "Could not create/open file:", fName
```